# MySQL full text index and regular index searching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, database-indexes

I have 3 columns of data I'm searching on: description (fulltext), lat (index), and lon (index).

When I do `SELECT id FROM table MATCH(description) AGAINST ('query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` everything processes quickly and works fine.

When I do `SELECT id FROM table WHERE lat BETWEEN a and b AND lon BETWEEN x and y` everything processes quickly and works fine.

When I merge the two where clauses together with a simple AND and do `SELECT id FROM table MATCH(description) AGAINST ('query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND (lat BETWEEN a and b AND lon BETWEEN x and y)` everything works fine, but it takes several seconds to process.

The first two queries will take 0.1 seconds and the last one will take 3+ seconds and I can't seem to figure out how to make it run quicker.  The description is full text indexes and the lat/lon columns are normal indexes.

Any ideas on what is slowing things down and/or how to fix it?  The table is InnoDB.

Comment: That's curious.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the slow query.

Comment: well its only going to use one of the two indexes for the query, surely.

Comment: select_type=SIMPLE, type=fulltext, possible_keys=<several>, key=search_fulltext, extra=Using where; Using filesort

Comment: @pala_ shouldn't it effectively do the same thing as an inner join?  Check fulltext index for a list of matching fulltext rows, check lat/lon index for a list of matching index rows, return the rows that are in both lists.

Comment: index merge doesnt apply to `fulltext`, see : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: @pala_ What would recommend to be the best solution here then?  The other issue is that the fulltext results could be bigger or the lat/lon results could be bigger, so in terms of doing a subquery where the indexes would have to be built on demand there doesn't seem to be much time saved in processing.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you could try separating the two portions, then joining the results

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the slowdown...  Note how each of the first two `SELECTs` return the `id`.  That is cheap because the id is included in any secondary index.

But when you have two parts to the `WHERE`, one index (`FULLTEXT`) is used to get the id, then it looks up the row to get the values (`lat`, `lng`) needed for the other part of the `WHERE`.  This involved another lookup on another BTree.  If everything necessary is in RAM, that is not too bad.  But if you need to hit the disk...

Let's check one possible fix...  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  That setting should normally be 70% of available RAM (assuming you have over 4GB).  Raising it to this value may diminish the I/O needed to perform the complex query, thereby speeding it up.

If that does not work, I have [a technique](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) that works efficiently with lat/lng searches.  I have not yet tried it together with `FULLTEXT`, so it may have some unexpected quirks.  However it does work very efficiently for lat/lng searches (better than you can get with just an ordinary `INDEX`).

Comment: It's an Amazon RDS instance with 7.5 gb of RAM and the entire database is small enough to be held in memory--there are only 1 or 2 reads from disk per hour.  innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 5.7 gb.  The lat lon lookup is to narrow the results for calculating a haversine equation for distance, so instead of calculating the haversine equation for 500k rows, it will just do the 100 or so that are within our lat/lon window.  The lat/lon window is square whereas our final results are a circle (search radius).

Answer (score 0):

A solution is provided in the question here: [MySQL index for normal column and full text column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706120/mysql-index-for-normal-column-and-full-text-column)

Essentially you need to run the two queries with a `UNION`.