# MySQL index for normal column and full text column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, union, query-performance, database-indexes

I'm trying to speed up a query for the below:

My table has around 4 million records.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  * FROM chrecords WHERE  company_number = 'test'  OR MATCH (company_name,registered_office_address_address_line_1,registered_office_address_address_line_2) AGAINST('test') LIMIT 0, 10;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys    | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | chrecords | ALL  | i_company_number | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2208348 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've created two indexes using the below:

```
ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords` ADD INDEX `i_company_number` (`company_number`);

ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords`ADD FULLTEXT(
    `company_name`,
    `registered_office_address_address_line_1`,
    `registered_office_address_address_line_2`
);
```

How can "combine" the two indexes however? As the above query takes 15+ seconds to execute (only using one index).

The entire table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `company_number` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_care_of` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_po_box` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_address_address_line_1` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_address_address_line_2` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_locality` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_region` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_country` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `registered_office_postal_code` VARCHAR(100) NULL
  );

ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords` ADD INDEX `i_company_name` (`company_name`);
ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords` ADD INDEX `i_company_number` (`company_number`);
ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords` ADD INDEX `i_registered_office_address_address_line_1` (`registered_office_address_address_line_1`);
ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords` ADD INDEX `i_registered_office_address_address_line_2` (`registered_office_address_address_line_2`);

ALTER TABLE `chapp`.`chrecords`ADD FULLTEXT(
    `company_name`,
    `registered_office_address_address_line_1`,
    `registered_office_address_address_line_2`
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  chrecords
            WHERE  company_number = 'test' 
            ORDER BY something
            LIMIT 10
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  cbrecords
            WHERE  MATCH (company_name, registered_office_address_address_line_1,
                                        registered_office_address_address_line_2)
                   AGAINST('test')
            ORDER BY something
            LIMIT 10
    ) 
    ORDER BY something
    LIMIT 10
```

Notes:

- No need for an outer `SELECT`
- Explicitly say `DISTINCT` (the default) or `ALL` (which is faster) so that you will know that you thought about whether dedupping was needed, versus speed.
- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is not very meaningful
- However, if you just want some rows to look at, you can remove the `ORDER BYs`.
- Yes the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` need to be repeated outside so that you can get the ordering correct and limit to 10.

If you need an `OFFSET`, the the inside need a full count, say `LIMIT 50` for 5 pages, the n the outside needs to skip to the 5th page:  `LIMIT 40,10`.

Comment: For the offset, would it also have the same result as having `LIMIT 40,10` on the inner select and `LIMIT 10` on the outside?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski - No.  Test case:  Put even numbers in one inner query; odd numbers in the other.  The desired 10 rows would come from the middles -- `LIMIT 40, 10` would have skipped over them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `UNION` rather than `OR`.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT  * 
        FROM chrecords 
        WHERE company_number = 'test'
    ) a
    UNION (
       SELECT * 
         FROM cbrecords
        WHERE MATCH (company_name, 
                     registered_office_address_address_line_1, 
                     registered_office_address_address_line_2)
              AGAINST('test') 
        LIMIT 0, 10
     ) b
```

If this helps, it's because MySQL struggles to use more than one index in a single subquery. This gives the query planner two queries.

You can run `EXPLAIN` on each of the subqueries separately to understand their performance. `UNION` just puts their results together and eliminates duplicates. If you want to keep the duplicates, do `UNION ALL`.

Please notice that lots of single-column indexes on MySQL tables are generally harmful to performance. You should refrain from creating indexes unless they're constructed to help specific queries.

Comment: Great! Running the provided query however gives me an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b' at line 1. It works if I remove `b`?

Comment: Yes, remove `b`.  The final `SELECT` is not generating a derived table so it doesn't need an alias.  The first one could also be rewritten without the derived table, but parentheses and unions are always a little bit mind-bending so it's an honest oversight.  For `b` to be needed here, `UNION (` would need to be written `UNION SELECT * FROM (` which isn't needed.  Note also, you should always use either `UNION DISTINCT` or `UNION ALL` for clarity.  `UNION` incorrectly worked as `UNION ALL` in older versions of MySQL when in fact `DISTINCT` is what should have been inferred. Fixed in 5.5.